# Help me understand these generic method warnings

Tags: java, generics

Folks,
I have a base class, say:

```
public class BaseType { private String id; ... }
```

and then three subclasses:

```
public class TypeA extends BaseType { ... }
public class TypeB extends BaseType { ... }
public class TypeC extends BaseType { ... }
```

I have a container class that maintains lists of objects of these types:

```
public class Container
{
    private List<TypeA> aList;
    private List<TypeB> bList;
    private List<TypeC> cList;

    // finder method goes here
}
```

And now I want to add a finder method to container that will find an object from one of the lists. The finder method is written as follows:

```
public <T extends BaseType> T find( String id, Class<T> clazz )
{
    final List<T> collection;
    if( clazz == TypeA.class )
    {
        collection = (List<T>)aList;
    }
    else if( clazz == TypeB.class )
    {
        collection = (List<T>)bList;
    }
    else if( clazz == TypeC.class )
    {
        collection = (List<T>)cList;
    }
    else return null;

    for( final BaseType value : collection )
    {
        if( value.getId().equals( id ) )
        {
            return (T)value;
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

My question is this: If I don't add all the casts to T in my finder above, I get compile errors. I think the compile should be able to infer the types based on parametrization of the generic method (). Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

-Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't take your manual type-checking into account when deciding whether an assignment is legal. As far as the analyzer is concerned, it needs to compile this line:

```
collection = (List<T>)aList;
```

so that it's valid when `T` is, say `TypeC`. And what looks like an assignment from `List<TypeA>` to `List<TypeC>`, without any casting, is something that it has to flag as an error.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the compiler should be able to infer the types based on parametrization of the generic method.

What you are saying is that the compiler should look at

```
if( clazz == TypeA.class )
```

and

```
Class<T> clazz
```

and from that infer that within the scope of the if statement `T` is indeed `TypeA`.

I agree that a clever compiler might be be able to do that, but unfortunately, the current Java compiler is not clever enough to infer this information.

This is similar to having to typecast after a successful instanceof check

```
if (a instanceof Something){
    ((Something)a).someMethod();
}
```

The reasoning would be that this advanced feature is not required very often, would take time to implement (would be bad if implemented incorrectly), and would probably make the compile time longer.

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<TypeA> aList;
private List<TypeB> bList;

public <T extends BaseType> T find(String id, Class<T> clazz) {
    final List<? extends BaseType> collection;
    if (clazz == TypeA.class) {
        collection = aList;
    } else if (clazz == TypeB.class) {
        collection = bList;
    }

    for (final BaseType value : collection) {
        if (value.getId().equals(id)) {
            return clazz.cast(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Does not solve the problem, either, because now the return type is not type-cast to the type of clazz anymore.

Comment: True. However at some point you will need to cast. Where would you rather cast? at the place you're passing in clazz or inside the called method.

Comment: @Thilo You can easily put `T` back and use `Class.cast`.

Comment: +1 for Class.cast (inside the method of course, to preserve the original signature).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the comments. I removed one cast by changing the for loop to read for( final T value : collection ) ... Anon's answer above addresses the need for explicit casts for the collection object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, correct code (without cast to `T`) will be like this:

```
for (final T value : collection) {
  if (value.getId().equals(id)) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

This is because your method declares that the return type is `T`, so the caller will be expecting a concrete return type like `TypeA` or `TypeB`. For example:

```
TypeA find("id", TypeA.class);
```

But if you generalize value type to `BaseType` then this may not match the concrete type. Because, as you know, `TypeA` is also `BaseType` but, `BaseType` is not necessarily a `TypeA`.

So java compiler will complain that it cannot convert `BaseType` to concrete type. To fix this you need to keep value type as `T` without generalising it. I know, `BaseType` and `T` do not sound like very different types, but that's how javac works.

Similar idea applies to the list casts. Since `List<T> collection` can potentially be of any concrete type, compiler cannot be sure that it is of any concrete type like `List<TypeA>` at compile time. Because idea behind generics is to be safe at compile time it gives you a compile error (unless you force it with casts).

Comment: Hi Rodion, I later changed my for loop just like to point out above. I still need cases for the collection assignments. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ditching reflection artefacts, and using a standard Strategy. Can't have generic enums unfortunately (although they can implement generic types supplying actual generic arguments).

```
private List<TypeA> aList;
private List<TypeB> bList;
private List<TypeC> cList;

public abstract class ListType<T extends BaseType> {
    /*private*/ abstract T get(Container container); // private isn't virtual.
    // Add extras to taste.
}
public static final ListType<TypeA> LIST_A = bew ListType<TypeA>() {
    /*private*/ ListType<TypeA> get(Container container) { return container.aList; }
};
public static final ListType<TypeB> LIST_B = bew ListType<TypeB>() {
    /*private*/ ListType<TypeB> get(Container container) { return container.bList; }
};
public static final ListType<TypeC> LIST_C = bew ListType<TypeC>() {
    /*private*/ ListType<TypeC> get(Container container) { return container.cList; }
};


public <T extends BaseType> T find(String id, ListType<T> type) {
    final List<T> collection = type.get(this);

    for (final T value : collection) {
        if (value.getId().equals(id)) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```